# Can this function have a minimum or maximum value? If yes, is my function correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, triangles, maxima-minima

The problem is the following (Ron Larson's Calculus for AP - 2nd Edition):
[image]

My solution to part a). was found by proving that the triangles are similar by the AA property (by comparing Alternate Interior Angles) and that they have a side ratio of "k". My answer to part a). is:

$$
A(x)=\frac{1}{2}dx (1-k)+\frac{1}{2}kdb.
$$

Part b) and c) however seem to indicate that there is a maximum and minimum function, but since the function is a line, there shouldn't be one. Now I am beginning to doubt the correctness of my solution for part a).

If a). is correct, then how do I proceed? If a). is incorrect, what mistake have I made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer to part a) is not correct.
The function $A(x)$ should be equal to
$$\frac{dx}{2}+\frac{D(b-x)}{2}$$
where $D$ can be obtained by the similarity of the two triangles
$$k(x)=\frac{D}{d}=\frac{b-x}{x}.$$
Hence, for $x\in (0,b]$, we have
$$A(x)=\frac{dx}{2}+\frac{d(b-x)^2}{2x}$$
which is not linear.
Taking the derivative we find
$$A'(x)=\frac{d}{2}\left(1+\frac{-2(b-x)x-(b-x)^2}{x^2}\right)=\frac{d(2x^2-b^2)}{2x^2}.$$
Hence, in $(0,b]$, $A$ has no the maximum value because $A(x)$ tends to $+\infty$ as $x\to 0^+$, and it attains the minimum value for $x=\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}$, that is when $|QS|=d(\sqrt{2}-1)$.

Comment: So is my solution to a). wrong, or is it just that the question is based on this form of $A(x)$?

Comment: @rayank97 The ratio $k$ depends on $x$, it is not constant!

Comment: I just realized and was about to edit my comment! Thank you so much!

Comment: @rayank97 Which book is this problem taken from?

Comment: Ron Larson's Calculus for AP - 2nd Edition.